# How to loop through a subarray of input objects and access value - ReactJS, cannot type in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I am working on this Form, which will allow to add multiple users and for each user is allowed add multiple goals. However each of these would be an input field. So far I have created the input field for users `firstName` and `lastName` and created a button to add more fields, however when I try to  map through the goals I am not able to get the value from the goal array.

Here's the code for each section

```js
//code for setting state
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([ { firstName: '', lastName: '' , goals: [{ mainGoal:'', subTasks:[] }]  }])//empty users array set when we start
```

Code for the form input

```js
 <label className="boldLabel">Add Member</label>
                                {users.map((input, index) => { //initially we are mappin through the empty users array and creating one field in the return section
                                return (
                                    <div className="singleOwnerField" key={index}>
                                        <Row>                                                                  
                                            <Col>       
                                                <input
                                                    name='firstName'
                                                    placeholder='First Name'
                                                    value={input.firstName}
                                                    onChange={event =>handleAddMore(index,event)}
                                                />
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>                                        
                                                <input
                                                name='lastName'
                                                placeholder='Last Name'
                                                value={input.lastName}
                                                onChange={event =>handleAddMore(index,event)}
                                            />
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>
                                            {input.goals.map((goal,i)=>{
                                                return( 
                                                    <input key={i}
                                                    name='mainGoal'
                                                    placeholder='Main Goal Name'
                                                     value={goal.mainGoal}
                                                    onChange={event =>handleAddGoal(index,i,event)}
                                                />
                                                )
                                            })}
```

Then the function I use to add firstName and lastName to the user object (this works as expected)

```js
    const handleAddMore = (index,event)=>{

        let data=[...users]
        data[index][event.target.name]=event.target.value
        setUsers(data) 
       
    }
```

Below is the function that is written to pick the input value from the goal input field

```js
const handleAddGoal = (index,goalIndex,event)=>{

        let goalsOfUser=[...users[index].goals]
        goalsOfUser[goalIndex][event.target.name]=event.target.value

          console.log("printing goalsOfUser: " + JSON.stringify(goalsOfUser))
 
        console.log("users" + JSON.stringify(users))
        
       
    }
```

However when I access goal.mainGoal in the input field (a snippet from the form above) **it doesn't show the value in the input field** (ie. cant type in )

```js
                                   <input key={i}
                                                    name='mainGoal'
                                                    placeholder='Main Goal Name'
                                                     value={goal.mainGoal}
                                                    onChange={event 
                                                            =>handleAddGoal(index,i,event)} />
```

I have tried console.logging in the handleAddGoal() function and it seems to print the user object with the first letter we type in the goal field but is not saved
[image]

I have tried adding setUser(user) but still the same behevior

```js
   const handleAddGoal = (index,goalIndex,event)=>{

        let goalsOfUser=[...users[index].goals]
        goalsOfUser[goalIndex][event.target.name]=event.target.value
 
        console.log("printing goalsOfUser: " + JSON.stringify(goalsOfUser))
    
        console.log("users" + JSON.stringify(users))
        setUsers(users)
  
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget to setUsers in handleAddGoal function?

Comment: I have tried adding 'setUser(user)' still the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handleAddGoal`  function you change the goal but you don't set the new data in `users` `array`.

you need to do like this

```
const handleAddGoal = (index,goalIndex,event)=>{
    let goalsOfUser=[...users[index].goals]
        goalsOfUser[goalIndex][event.target.name]=event.target.value

    const tempUsers = [...users]
    tempUsers[index].goals = goalsOfUser;

    setUsers(tempUsers)       
}
```